# Remove or reduce question feeds in chat?

Tags: discussion

I've been hanging out in the chatroom and I've noticed that the question feed kinda swamps out other content. There's not a lot of chatting going on, but I wonder if the feed isn't making that even harder. AIUI the feed won't prevent the room from auto-freezing for inactivity.

So, what does everyone think? Should we reduce or remove the new question feed from the chatroom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can remove the news feed. Reviving the chat is far easier when the conversations aren't disturbed by it. If the people see some activity, they might get motivated to contribute.

Comment: Sounds good. FWIW I think we should keep the Meta feed since that's even slower (and useful to draw attention).